# How to change the width of inline buttons to chat width, instead of message width using js

Tags: telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I can't find a way to make the button to fit the chat are rather than the bot send.message text width.

This is how it looks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDAoC.png)

**The code for the first question is:**

```
bot.onText(/\/start/, (msg) => {
  const chatId = msg.chat.id;
  bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Hi! I am Find My Bridge search Bot. Are you looking for a blockchain bridge?', {
    reply_markup: {
      inline_keyboard: [
        [
          { text: 'Yes', callback_data: 'yes' },
          { text: 'No', callback_data: 'no' }
        ]
      ]
    }
  });
});
```

I've tried using resize.keyboard but it doesn't work and can't find a way to do it